# Does declaring variables in a loop waste memory?

Tags: javascript

Consider this:

```
var i = 0;
var isEight = false;

while(true){
    if( i === 8) {
        isEight = true;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

versus this:

```
var i = 0;

while(true){
    var isEight = false; // moved declaration inside 
    if( i === 8) {
        isEight = true;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

The example is contrived but you get the idea. How does Javascript respond when the declaration of `isEight` is brought inside the loop?

Does a new memory space get allocated every time that line runs? Will this be a serious issue if the loop runs many many times?

---

Update: Since alex pointed out, what about using `let` instead of `var` in this case.

Comment: `isOdd` should be `isEight` right?

Comment: @TryingToImprove yes, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The declaration is hoisted so it's unlikely that there's any practical difference. In any case it would depend on the JS engine.

Comment: It would be a more interesting question if you were using `let` there instead of `var`.

Comment: Declaration of variable is done first anyway in Javascript so I believe they're not declared again if you put them in a loop?

Comment: `let` is *designed* for use cases like this, so it would be highly unlikely that JS engines wouldn't know how to manage memory correctly.